# How to force stop a thread if it has been running for more than 5 minutes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using threads for http server. But there are times when for some reason the thread freezes and this loads my program. I need to analyze if the thread is running for more than 5 minutes, then kill it. How can I do that?

```
import socketserver
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler, ThreadingHTTPServer

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    
    def do_POST(self):
        #do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer(("", 8080), Handler) as httpd:
    logger.info("LISTEN SERVER")
```

Comment: implement a timeout feature within the logic of the thread

Comment: Please provide us with the code example so that we can help you more!!

Then take a look at how to ask good questions on StackOverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Unutu124
How can we run the code! Does it seem that socketserver is not defined in your program?

Comment: sorry,add import

Answer (score 0):

We can use the event here. https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading

If we use the timeout, it way cause some errors. Therefore using the .join() with a timeout for the initial decision to trigger the event is fine, final verification should be made using a .join() without a timeout.

```
t.join(300)
if t.is_alive():
    print "thread is running, setting event to kill thread."
    e.set()
else:
    print "thread is  terminated."

# At this moment, Thread might still be alive. Verify thread shutdown by joining again without a timeout.
t.join()
```

Comment: Does the set method stop the thread completely? I thought he would block it

Comment: If the thread's call to isSet() returns right before this call to set(), then the thread will still perform the full 1 second sleep and the rest of the loop before finally stopping.

Comment: sorry, I still didn’t understand something ... isSet is not used in your example .. if you just use e.set (), then the flow will completely stop and then the garbage collector will remove it from memory?

Comment: by e.set() that you mean e = threading.Event()?

Comment: This won't work with OP's example, since they're not in control of the socketserver's main loop thread.

Comment: @AKX, how else can I use  TCPServer?